# How to write using tokio Framed LinesCodec?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The following code reads from my server successfully, however I cannot seem to get the correct syntax or semantics to write back to the server when a particular line command is recognized. Do I need to create a `FramedWriter`? Most examples I have found split the socket but that seems overkill I expect the codec to be able to handle the bi-directional io by providing some async write method.

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.3", features = ["full"] }
tokio-util = { version = "0.4", features = ["codec"] }
```

```
//! main.rs
use tokio::net::{ TcpStream };
use tokio_util::codec::{ Framed, LinesCodec };
use tokio::stream::StreamExt;
use std::error::Error;
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let saddr = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 8081); 
    let conn = TcpStream::connect(saddr).await?;

    let mut server = Framed::new(conn, LinesCodec::new_with_max_length(1024));

    while let Some(Ok(line)) = server.next().await {
        match line.as_str() {
            "READY" => println!("Want to write a line to the stream"),
            _ => println!("{}", line),
        }
    }

    Ok({})
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.5.0/tokio_util/codec/struct.Framed.html), `Framed` implements `Stream` and `Sink` traits. [`Sink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.8/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html) defines only the bare minimum of low-level sending methods. To get the high-level awaitable methods like `send()` and `send_all()`, you need to use the [`SinkExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.8/futures/sink/trait.SinkExt.html) extension trait.

For example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bebe6082a0fc3c3a0d86f30dff93be21)):

```
use futures::sink::SinkExt;
// ...

while let Some(Ok(line)) = server.next().await {
    match line.as_str() {
        "READY" => server.send("foo").await?,
        _ => println!("{}", line),
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me however I had to construct a variable to pass to the send function it would not take quoted chars.  let mut msg = "Some request text\n";  server.send(msg);

Comment: @sfanjoy That's interesting - can you edit the code in the playground to show the error?

Comment: You are correct. I was attempting to use server.send_all() when I encountered the error. I switched from quoted chars to a variable. When send compiled I left it alone. I am new to rust and still learning.

Comment: @sfanjoy No problem, I was genuinely curious, as I have little experience with tokio. Despite the similarity in naming, `send_all` is a completely different beast, it forwards the whole contents of the given stream into the sink you call it on. Since it must read from the stream, and therefore mutate it, it requires a mutable reference to the stream.